# Error al crear y registrar usuarios en firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una app en Android Stuido que tiene un login, para hacer la funcionabilidad estoy usando Firebase, ya cree mi proyecto en firebase y lo conecte con mi app en android studio, mi problema viene cuando intento crear un nuevo usuario con "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" o intentar ingresar con un usuario que este en la base de datos con "signInWithEmailAndPassword", no crea usuarios y si lo creo manualmente desde la consola de Firebase y uso el metodo para ingresar tampoco sucede nada, nose que pueda ser, dejo el codigo del login:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

private Button btnCreateAccount;
private Button btnSingIn;
private EditText editEmail;
private EditText editPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnCreateAccount    = findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccount);
    btnSingIn           = findViewById(R.id.btnSingIn);
    editEmail           = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editPassword        = findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

    inicitalize();

    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createAccount(editEmail.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    btnSingIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            singIn(editEmail.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void inicitalize(){
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(firebaseUser != null){
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - signed_in" + firebaseUser.getUid());
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - signed_in" + firebaseUser.getEmail());
            }else{
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
}

private void createAccount(String email, String password){
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create Account Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create Account Unsuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void singIn(String email, String password){
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isComplete() && task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Unsuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

}

En la consola de Firebase en la configuración me muestra que esta conectado con mi proyecto en Android Studio con su llave SHA-1 y he puesto permisos de internet y sin internet y sigue igual, en mi gradle estoy usando:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
```

de antemano muchas gracias aquien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chequea que tengas habilitada la funcion de crear usuarios con email y contraseña desde Firebase

### Paso 1

Dirígete a la solapa **Authentication**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Paso 2

Ve a la solapa **Métodos de inicio de sesion**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Paso 3

Chequea que este habilitada la opcion de crear usuarios con email y contraseña ( si no es asi, activala y vuelve a intentar ingresar desde tu app)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]